# Create group subtotals for columns with conditional sums of other columns in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is going to be pretty hard to explain, and was very hard to search answers for.

My dataset contains information for Employee's work orders, with their estimated cost and then the actual cost based on the tasks completed.  The query looks like

```
Employee  WorkOrder  Planned  Task  Actual
John      j101       500      1     300
John      j101       500      2     300
John      J102       500      1     100
John      j101       500      2     200
Chris     C201       300      1     150
Chris     C201       300      2     150
Chris     C202       400      1     200
Chris     C202       400      2     100
Chris     C202       400      3     100
Chris     C202       400      4     100
```

I'm trying to create a report that looks similar this:  [image: Sample report]

Each Work Order has an estimated cost at the header level, which is compared against the sum of actual costs of its tasks.  The "Expected Cost" column takes the max of the planned cost and summed actual cost.

The expression for that works  properly and looks like

```
IIf(Fields!PlannedCost.Value >= Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value),
           Fields!PlannedCost.Value,Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value))
```

I now have to subtotal these Expected Costs by Employee, and then Grand Total the entire set of data.

I've been trying to wrap that IIF in another SUM expression, but it's giving me values that's way higher than what it should be.  I read somewhere (can't find the link) that I have to use scope for the sums, but it's not helping.

I tried the following, but the value is still 3-4 times higher than it should be

```
Sum(
    IIf(Fields!PlannedCost.Value >= Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value, "table1_Details_Group"), 
        Fields!PlannedCost.Value,
        Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value, "table1_Details_Group")
        )
    )
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm hoping I'm just missing something easy, since this seems like it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue with the help of [this blog post](https://www.magenium.com/Information/Articles/SSRS-Reports)

I had assumed it was my task SUM expressions that were causing the issue, but it was actually the PlannedCost column.  When I wrapped that in another SUM, it counted it for every line in the data, which seems so obvious now.

Anyways, the Work Order subtotal remained the same.

The subtotal by Employee changed to (**Note the "Max" function**)

```
=FormatCurrency(
Sum(
    IIf(Max(Fields!PlannedCost.Value,"table1_WONum") >= Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value, "table1_WONum"), 
            Max(Fields!PlannedCost.Value,"table1_WONum"),
            Sum(Fields!TaskActualCost.Value, "table1_WONum")
        )
    )
,2)
```

The grand total expression is the same as the Employee subtotal.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.